# When targeting EU digital markets, is it enough to be GDPR compliant, or does one need to check the privacy laws of each EU country separately?

Tags: gdpr, privacy, european-union, data-protection

When targeting EU digital markets, is it enough to be GDPR compliant with regards to data privacy, or does one need to check the privacy laws of each EU country separately?

There exists an argument that GDPR is just the "lowest common denominator", and there might be legal risks with per-country privacy legislation. However, my impression has been that GDPR harmonized the legislation so that businesses wouldn't need to worry about compliance in individual countries (within the scope of privacy legislation, of course).

Is doing per-country risk reviews being overanxious – especially as they might turn out to be very expensive or time consuming – or is it due diligence?

Comment: Obviously you should get advice from an EU lawyer with a relevant practice before making any firm decisions, but the question is interesting in the abstract and ought to remain on the site.  If you can edit the question to make it less about you and your company, it will be less likely to be closed as a request for legal advice.  (Such requests are off topic.)  (Also, I think you're probably right; such harmonization for ease of doing business is usually a goal of the EU, and would explain why GDPR is a regulation rather than a directive, but I do not know for sure.)

Comment: In general, EU rules apply everywhere in the EU, except in the country where you are, where the local rules might override EU rules. So if you were for example in Germany, you should check EU rules and German rules. If you are outside the EU, the EU rules alone would count. On the other hand, check how much at risk you are if you get it wrong, and you might want to consult a lawyer.

Comment: The pre-GDPR Data Protection Directive was such a "lowest common denominator" law. However, the GDPR is an EU Regulation, and pre-empts national deviations, except where expressly allowed ("derogations"). There are differences in enforcement though. Foreign companies do not benefit from one-stop-shop enforcement, so many international companies create an Irish subsidiary. Data protection is just a small aspect though. You might still encounter national differences e.g. with respect to consumer rights. Also, ePrivacy ("cookie law") is still just a Directive.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the pointer, edited the question. I hope it's general enough now. And yes, I'm going to get advice from a lawyer, but decided also to post this here, because this is a question I hardly couldn't find with a bit of googling. Everybody's just talking whether they need to support GDPR at all.